# I want to save the mongodb query results to postgresql using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postgresql, nosql

this is query result I got from MongoDB and now I want to save these results in PostgreSQL using `Nodejs

```
{"username":"ABC","date":"2020-03-09T07:00:00.000Z","distance":0}
{"username":"DEF","date":"2020-03-09T07:00:00.000Z","distance":0.0625}
{"username":"GHI","date":"2020-03-09T06:00:00.000Z","distance":0}
{"username":"JKL","date":"2020-03-09T07:00:00.000Z","distance":0.0062}
{"username":"MNO","date":"2020-03-09T08:00:00.000Z","distance":0.0016}
{"username":"XYZ","date":"2020-03-09T08:00:00.000Z","distance":0}
{"username":"XYZ","date":"2020-03-09T07:00:00.000Z","distance":0}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many packages to help with this, I found the easiest to learn and use was Sequelize, once you learn the syntax it will work most SQL databases you want to interact with. See the excellent getting started page:

https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/getting-started.html

I spent a lot of time trying out different packages to interact with a sqlite database without having to set up all my own classes, Sequelize was the first one that was intuitive.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it.